# Fixing sed expression

Tags: linux, sed

I'm using "hosts" files from different sources and to unblock some sites i use the following SED code:

```
sed -i '/0.0.0.0 internet.com/s/^/#/g' /tmp/hosts
```

Result:

It puts # in front of

```
0.0.0.0 internet.com
```

but also

```
0.0.0.0 internet.com.site
```

I need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match complete lines, then specify complete lines:

```
sed -i '/^0.0.0.0 internet.com$/s/^/#/g' /tmp/hosts
```

The `^` means start o fline, as you already use in the search pattern for the replace.

The `$` means end of line.

So `^0.0.0.0 internet.com$` will only match a line the is exactly `0.0.0.0 internet.com`, not a line that only contains it as a substring.

Comment: I think `sed -i 's/^0.0.0.0 internet.com$/#&/'` is simpler and does the same thing.

Comment: @seshoumara thank you very much, your code worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use. It also handles entries that contain aliases

```
$ cat -vet hosts
0.0.0.0 internet.com internet$
0.0.0.0 internet.com^Iinternet$
0.0.0.0 internet.com$
0.0.0.0 internet.com.site$

$ sed  's/^0.0.0.0 internet.com\( \|\t\|$\)/# &/' hosts
# 0.0.0.0 internet.com internet
# 0.0.0.0 internet.com  internet
# 0.0.0.0 internet.com
0.0.0.0 internet.com.site
```

Obviously, it could be easily improved to handle multiple white space if needed.